# How To Work With Webpack And API Server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, webpack, mean-stack

I am new the MEAN stack.
I started this nice journey with an Angular2 template,
http://akveo.com/ng2-admin/

However, I got some questions:
When I am developing the front-end part, I start webpack-dev-server.

1. Do I need to start webpack-dev-server when the project is in production situation?
2. If I have a NodeJS API server, do I need to start both "node server" and "npm start" in production situation?
3. In terms of file structure, how can I combine ng2-admin starter (based on Webpack) and the NodeJS API server in the same project?

These questions make me so much confused.
Thank you and look forward to your great answers.